# How do I add my own JS to a Razor view?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to include lines 4-6 in the Scripts section of the page. The code below is in my view. Instead of being written to  it prints to the page. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Somehow it seems this is a very uncommon thing to do as I am not finding examples of how to do it correctly.

```
1 @section Scripts {
2   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
3   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datetimepicker")
4   $(function() {
5     $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker();
6   });
7 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep it inside the script tag

```
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datetimepicker")
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
     $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: See I thought it was already going to go in the <script> tag. This worked.

Answer (score 1):

You script needs to be in a `<script>` tag

```
@section Scripts {
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datetimepicker")
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker();
    });
  </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your view uses the _Layout.cshtml page then you can add a custom section like this at your _Layout.cshtml page:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

If you want all you page should require this section then set `require:true`

In your view you code should look like this:

```
  @section scripts{
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datetimepicker")
    <script>
     $(function() {
     $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker();
     });
    </script>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a script tag and put this code inside the script tag

```
@section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datetimepicker")
   <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
            $(function() {
         $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker();
       });
      });
    </script>
  }
```

But There might be a problem because sometimes the asp does not render the scripts . Also you do need to render the scripts in the partial views in case.